# Not able to add cookie with response.addCookie in a JSP

Tags: jsp, cookies

I am adding a cookie at server side from my JSP page like this:

```
Cookie fooCookie = new Cookie("foo", "test");
fooCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
fooCookie.setDomain("localhost");
fooCookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie( fooCookie );
```

Once the page is loaded, I am checking to see if the cookie was added. For that I run this command in chrome console:

```
alert(document.cookie)
```

But I am not seeing the cookie I just added in the alert output.

The application being tested is running on `http://localhost:8088`

What am I doing wrong? I am using sitemesh to generate my output.

Comment: try to comment the part of the code you set the path, and see if it works... also open the developer mode in the browser and check if the cookie was created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually what was happening was that the jsp pages could not update the response headers (may be because of sitemesh). I moved the code to controller class and it works.